# How do you pass in a property when instantiating a React component

Tags: reactjs

This is what my component looks like:

```
class PersonProfileBadge extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.alias = this.props.alias;
        //this.alias = 'hardcodedvalue';
    }

    render() {
        return e(
            'img',
            {
                src: `https://internal-cdn.com/somepath/?uid=${this.alias}`,
                className: 'profile_photo'
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And now I want to instantiate it and render it like so

```
const navProfilePicture = document.querySelector('#profile_image');
ReactDOM.render((new PersonProfileBadge({'alias': 'stupidfatcat'})), navProfilePicture)
```

But doing so spits out this error

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater, alias}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I'm pretty new to react and I have no idea how to properly do this.

Doing this works but then I can't pass in the property for the alias

```
ReactDOM.render(e(PersonProfileBadge), navProfilePicture);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *proper* way to do this would be to get your environment to support JSX instead:

```
const navProfilePicture = document.querySelector('#profile_image');
ReactDOM.render(
  <PersonProfileBadge alias='stupidfatcat' />,
  navProfilePicture
);
```

But if you can't do that, use `React.createElement` when calling `ReactDOM.render` - not *just* in your component's render method:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  e(PersonProfileBadge, {'alias': 'stupidfatcat'}),
  navProfilePicture
);
```

Comment: Ah! Understood, yeah doesn't seem like my environment supports jsx at the moment but I'll look into it. The second approach worked though!